# sikuli - The windows application opened through sikuli is opened as minimized, how to solve?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I have a simple sikuli script which will open a windows exe file(in below cmd "run.bat" opens a windows exe application)

```
App.open(r"SENINFO_V100R002C00SPC700\run.bat")
```

The problem i am facing is, the exe application is opened sometimes as minimized in taskbar, So next sikuli cmds which are expecting some image are failing. 
How to solve this, please help

Answer (score 0):

Try **App.focus()** method instead of **App.open()**